# Homework help finding pdf's of y given pdf's of x - stuck

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If anyone can give me the steps on how to find pdf$\,'$s of $y$ given $x$.

Let X be a continuous random variable with *probability density function*
given by
$$
{\rm f}\left(x\right)
=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
{1 \over x^{2}} & \mbox{if} & x \geq 1
\\[2mm]
0&&\mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
$$
A Random Variable $Y$ is given by
$$
Y = \left\lbrace\begin{array}{lclrcl}
2x    & \mbox{if} &\quad X & \geq & 2
\\[2mm]
x^{2} & \mbox{if} &\quad X & < & 2 
\end{array}\right.
$$
Find the probability density function of $Y$.

I would need to take the cumulative density function of ${\rm f}\left(x\right)$ with limits of $Y$ ?.  Then derivative of that function or ?.  Any help to get on the right track much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your definition of $Y$ is right? I ask because it can never happen that $X<1$ since $f_X(x)=0$ for $x<1$ so that $\Pr(X<1)=0$.

Comment: No, you are right.  This problem is driving me crazy so I didn't define Y correctly.  Let me edit it, It should be X < 2, not 1.

Comment: I would be tempted to write $$F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\leq y)=\Pr(Y\leq y|X<2)\Pr(X<2)+\Pr(Y\leq y|X\geq 2)\Pr(X\geq 2)$$ and work from there

Comment: So this is a conditional probability density function?

Comment: Double check your problem statement. Are you being asked to find a conditional PDF or not?

Comment: No nothing in the original statement mentions conditional probability.

Answer (score 1):

One strategy is to find the cumulative distribution function $F_Y(y)$ of $Y$, and then differentiate. It is clear that $F_Y(y)=0$ if $y\le 1$.

We are told that $Y=X^2$ if $X\lt 2$. So if $1\lt y\lt 4$, we have 
$$F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr(X^2\le y)=\Pr(X\le \sqrt{y})=\int_1^{\sqrt{y}} \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx.$$ If we just want to find the density, we can use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to find the derivative without calculating the integral. However, in this case the integration is easy.

If $y\ge 4$, the calculation is similar. We get $F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr(X\le y/2)=\int_1^{y/2} \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx$.

Comment: You are welcome. One can use *transformations*, or one can travel through the cdf. Transformations are often more efficient. I chose the cdf route because I think one retains more control. But transformations are certainly a good way of handling the problem.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help - FINALLY I'm understanding the mechanics of this.

Answer (score 0):

The formula is $f_Y(y)=\begin{cases} f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \left| \frac{d}{dy} g^{-1}(y) \right| ,y\in \mathcal Y \\ 0,\text{else} \end {cases}$

First build the inverse function of $Y=g(x)$ (with definition set)

Then insert $g^{-1}(y)$ in f(x). Keep in mind, that $f(x) =0$, if $x \leq 1$.

Then calculate $\left| \frac{d}{dy} g^{-1}(y) \right|$.

greetings,

calculus